# Pardot ObjectChangeLog using huge amounts of data

Tags: pardot

In one of our sandboxes we are currently over our data limit.  One of the main culprits is ObjectChangeLog, which is using nearly 50% of our allowed data.  I've queried the object and found that it has 32,000 records.  I really don't think we need this information, but I don't want to delete it if it serves a needed purpose.  The data has been saved since we implemented Pardot(5 months).  In our production instance it saves 2 days worth of information, then I'm assuming deletes it.  Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the object is needed:

> ObjectChangeLogs. This allows the connector to create prospects in Pardot as they are created in Salesforce. - [from Pardot Doc](http://www.pardot.com/faqs/salesforce/installing-pardot-appexchange-application/)

Please contact salesforce and pardots technical support to make sure that the object is needed for sync.

Comment: Thanks we are chatting with them right now.  It seems that our Connector became disconnected.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Custom Setting `pi` namespace - `Public Setting for LogObjectTrigger`  which has a list entry `LogObjectEmailFieldTriggerHandler` which has a checkbox `Disable OCL Trigger and Batch Processing`.

Tick that to ON and logs won't get created.